# The answer shown is not its current revision

Tags: support, questions, answers

I was looking at a question, and I noticed that [one of its answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1759/199) started with greetings.

> [image: screenshot]

I clicked on the "edit" link, but with my surprise the greetings were not present.

> [image: screenshot]

Looking at the [post's revisions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/1759/revisions), such text has never never been present. Supposing it was removed from a background script (which I remember was run once to remove greetings at the beginning of a post), why was the text still showed?

I added two empty lines at the beginning of the post, and the greetings are not anymore shown. Still, I am wondering what happened.

Comment: This happened to me earlier as well...can't remember exactly what question it was on though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some "greetings" cleanups done last year on the history tables that might have, er, missed cleaning up their associated posts' text.

Your fix was the correct one.